# Laravel 5.2 com paginação

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.2

Tenho a seguinte função dentro do controller

```
public function home()
{
    $igrejas = Igreja::paginate(3);
    $igrejas->setPath('igrejas');
    return view('admin/igrejas/home')->with('igrejas', $igrejas);
}
```

Preciso que seja retornado além da paginação, por order de criação, que na primeira página apareça os últimos registros. Da forma que está o sistema traz nas últimas páginas o últimos registros, preciso do inverso.

Comment: Se você tiver uma coluna data_cadastro com default now() você pode ordenar por essa coluna usando o método do Miguel abaixo, mas trocando o valor da coluna.

Comment: Exato @PeterParker, isso vai até dar ao mesmo se houver uma coluna com auto-increment (como é o caso do id por convenção). Fica automáticamente ordenado por criação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma pequena alteração:

```
...
Igreja::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(3);
...
```

Note que estou a partir do princípio que existe uma coluna `id auto-increment` nessa tabela, caso não exista ordene pela coluna que gostaria

Comment: Funcionou com esta alteração, obrigado !

Comment: De nada @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos . Ainda bem que resolveu